# Deploy Spring cloud data flow on Google compute engine with data flow scheduling feature, and without using K8s or Cloud Foundry

Tags: google-cloud-platform, spring-batch, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-dataflow

As they mention in the [documentation](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/), there is only 3 ways how you can install spring cloud data flow:

1. local (manually or using docker compose)
2. Cloud foundry
3. K8s

And local platform is intented to be used only for development, so for production you will be forced to go with the second or third options.

Also if you want to use the scheduling feature, it's not available for local platform. SCDF scheduling feature is supported on Cloud Foundry and Kubernetes using the CF and K8s schedulers.

The problem is that I have a Spring Batch application hosted on Google compute engine, and I want to host also SDCF with scheduling feature on compute engine, because in the company I worked with, they want to host all their projects on Google cloud platform.

I have searched if I can use Google cloud platform as a provider for cloud foundry and use compute engine, but didn't find a solution.

So my question is, is there any way I can host Spring cloud data flow on Google compute engine with scheduling feature, and without using K8s ?

Answer (score 1):

An option may be to run SCDF in GKE. Using the helm chart assembled from bitnami, you can easily integrate with Cloud SQL and GAR. We run this setup with great success.